# A motion model to track a moving object using the condensation algorithm

Tags: probability, monte-carlo, particle-filter

I have implemented the condensation algorithm in order to track a moving object in video sequences, however the predictive step does not work properly, so the samples moves excessively compared to the actual movement of the object.

Maybe I need to estimate more accurately the velocity of the object: how to estimate the two components of velocity?